# REACT-Send requests the selected dish options ids to my backend not working

Tags: reactjs, react-select

How can I retrieve the `dishId` selected from my options react - select that shows me the`dishType` in order to send them my parent component `FormRender` and to the backend.

My first dropdown shows me: `Menu1`, `Menu2`...

My second one: `type2`...

So if I click on`type4`, how can I store the related `dishId`(here = 4). I can click on several values i.e: `type2` and`type3`.

How do I keep the dish ids i.e : `2` and `3` and send them to my `FormRender` parent

Menus(first page of my multi - step form):

```
export default function Menus() {
    const [selectionMenus, setSelectionMenus] = useState({});
    const [selectionDishes, setSelectionDishes] = useState({});
    const [menus, setMenus] = useState([])
    const [date, setDate] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .post(url)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                setMenus(res.data.menus);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, []);

    const names = menus?.map(item => {
        return {
            label: item.menuId,
            value: item.name
        }
    })

    const types = menus?.flatMap(item => {
        return item.dishes.map(d => ({
            label: d.dishId,
            value: d.dishType
        }))
    })
    const handle = (e) => {
        if (e?.target?.id === undefined) return setInfo(e);
        if (e?.target?.id === undefined) return setSelectionMenus(e);
        if (e?.target?.id === undefined) return setSelectionDishes(e);
        switch (e.target.id) {
            case "date":
                setDate(e.target.value);
                break;            
                ...
            default:
}
    }
};
return (
    <>
        <form>
            <div>My menus</div>
            <label>
                Dishes :
                <Dropdown
                    options={names}
                    value={selectionMenus}
                    setValue={setSelectionMenus}
                    isMulti={true}
                />
            </label>
            <label>
                <Dropdown
                    options={types}
                    value={selectionDishes}
                    setValue={setSelectionDishes}
                    isMulti={true}
                />
            </label>
            <label>
                Date:
                <div>
                    <input
                        type="date"
                        name='date'
                        value={date}
                        onChange={handle}
                        id="date"
                    />
                </div>
            </label>
            ...
        </form>
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => nextPage({ selectionDishes, selectionMenus, date })}>Next</button>
        </div>
    </>
);
}
```

Here the parent Component `FormRender` that is supposed to retrieve the values of all dishId selected and send them to the backend:

```
export default function FormRender() {
    const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(0);
    const [info, setInfo] = useState();
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    const headers = ["Menus", "Details", "Final"];
    const steps = [
        <Menus
            nextPage={(menu) => {
                setInfo(menu);
                setCurrentStep((s) => s + 1);
            }}
        />,
        <Details
            backPage={() => setCurrentStep((s) => s - 1)}
            nextPage={setUser}
        />,
        <Final />
    ];
    useEffect(() => {
        if (info === undefined || user === undefined) return;
        const data = {
            date: info.date,
            id: //list of dishId selected but don't know how to do that??
        };
    }, [info, user]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <Stepper steps={headers} currentStep={currentStep} />
                <div >{steps[currentStep]}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Dropdown:

```
export default function Dropdown({ value, setValue, style, options, styleSelect, isMulti = false }) {

    function change(option) {
        setValue(option.value);
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
            {value && isMulti === false ? (
                <Tag
                    selected={value}
                    setSelected={setValue}
                    styleSelect={styleSelect}
                />
            ) : (
                <Select
                    value={value}
                    onChange={change}
                    options={options}
                    isMulti={isMulti}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

Here my json from my api:

{
    "menus": [
        {
            "menuId": 1,
            "name": "Menu1",
            "Description": "Descritption1",
            "dishes": [
                {
                    "dishId": 2,
                    "dishType": "type2"
                },
                {
                    "dishId": 3,
                    "dishType": "type3"
                },
                {
                    "dishId": 4,
                    "dishType": "type4"
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already store the selected values inside the *selectionMenus* and *selectionDishes* states. So, if you want to send them to the parent *FormRender* component you can instead create those two states inside that component like this:

```
export default function FormRender() {
 const [selectionMenus, setSelectionMenus] = useState();
 const [selectionDishes, setSelectionDishes] = useState();
 ....
}
```

Then pass those values to the *Menus* component:

```
<Menus
 selectionMenus={selectionMenus}
 setSelectionMenus={setSelectionMenus}
 selectionDishes={selectionDishes}
 setSelectionDishes={setSelectionDishes}
 nextPage={(menu) => {
  setInfo(menu);
  setCurrentStep((s) => s + 1);
 }}
/>
```

Subsequently, you will have to remove the state from the *Menus* component and use the one you receive from props:

```
export default function Menus({ selectionMenus, setSelectionMenus, selectionDishes, setSelectionDishes }) {
 /*const [selectionMenus, setSelectionMenus] = useState({}); //remove this line
 const [selectionDishes, setSelectionDishes] = useState({});*/ //remove this line
...
}
```

Finally, you can use inside your *useEffect* hook the two states and map them to only get the selected ids:

```
useEffect(() => {
 // ... other logic you had

 if(selectionDishes?.length && selectionMenus?.length){
  const data = {
    date: info.date,
    id: selectionDishes.map(d => d.dishId),
    idMenus: selectionMenus.map(m => m.menuId)
  };
 }
}, [info, user, selectionMenus, selectionDishes]);
```

Comment: And the `Next` button  in my `Menus`,, do I need to change something too ?

Comment: Just add the prop nextPage in the argument like this export default function Menus({ selectionMenus, setSelectionMenus, selectionDishes, setSelectionDishes, nextPage }) {

Comment: thanks, do you have idea about this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72517068/react-how-can-i-display-string-data-from-my-api-with-react-wysiwyg) please ?

Comment: If I solved it please make sure to tick the answer as correct

Comment: Why when I select on a `dishType` option in my dropdown I get in my console.log I got `selectionDishes: undefined` and `setSelectionDishes : ƒ bound dispatchSetState() {}`?

Answer (score -1):

react-select has options to format the component:

`getOptionLabel: option => string` => used to format the label or how to present the options in the UI,

`getOptionValue: option => any` => used to tell the component what's the actual value of each option, here you can return just the id

`isOptionSelected: option => boolean` => used to know what option is currently selected

`onChange: option => void` => do whatever you want after the input state has changed

`value => any` => if you customize the above functions you may want to handle manually the value

Hope it helps you