# Why do I get a blank page when I click on my textarea zone with react-wysiwyg?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-draft-wysiwyg

After getting the API response inside `MenuItemDetail`, I set it to the `responses` state, which is then passed down to Tabs, then TabContent. Here, I want to read  correctly its resp and name props then display whatever they contain in the two corresponding editors i.e  `respEditor` and `nameEditor` (`resp` and `name` fields in my json from API).

I can retrieve my `resp` and `name` from my API, but when I try to click on the textarea zone in order to add or modify the content  I got a **blank page**, and get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: contentState.getBlockMap is not a function
```

i've check this question on the forum : [DraftJS - contentState.getBlockMap is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48742791/draftjs-contentstate-getblockmap-is-not-a-function)

I really really don't know why

```
const TabContent = ({  onChange, resp, , status }) => {
  const [respEditor, setRespEditor] = useState(
    EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromHTML(resp !== null ? resp : ""))
  );

  function respChange(state) {
    setRespEditor(state);
    onChange({
      resp: convertToRaw(state.getCurrentContent()),
      status
    });
  }



  let handle = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      let res = await fetch("", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          resp: convertToHTML(respEditor.getCurrentContent()),             
          status: status
        })
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handle}>        
      <Editor
        editorState={respEditor}
        onEditorStateChange={respChange}
        wrapperclassName="wrapperclassName"
        editorclassName="editorclassName"
        toolbar={{
          options: ["inline"],
          inline: { inDropdown: false }
        }}
      />

      
          <input
            type="radio"
            value="B"
            onChange={(e) =>
              onChange({
                resp,
                status: e.target.value
              })
            }          
          <input
         
        </span>
      </div>

    
    </form>
  );
};
```

Here is my json from api for `menuId:1`:

```
[
  {
    "menuId": 1,
    "name": "Menu1", 
    "trust":1,   
    "dishes": {
      "meat": "N/A",
      "vegetables": "pea"
    },
    "list": [
      {
        "resp": "resp1",
        "question": "question1",
        "link": "",
        "name": "Name1",
        "status": "Finished"
      },
      {
        "resp": "resp2",
        "question": "question2",
        "link": "http://mylink.com",
        "name": "Name2",
        "status": "Saved"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 6):

Solution Codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-wysiwyg-draft-js-ecmpth?file=/src/TabContent.js

**Edited**

You can use `convertFromHTML` from `draft-convert` to parse HTML string to `EditorContent`. Install `draft-convert`, which is the recommended way in the official example. (reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36904924/9744063)

```bash
npm install draft-convert
```

```js
import { convertFromHTML } from ‘draft-convert’;

const [respState, setRespState] = useState(EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromHTML(resp)));
const [nameState, setNameState] = useState(EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromHTML(name)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've tried but I still  can't see my data from my api, typically, I'm not able to see  my `resp` and `name` fields... I've added the output of my json for example in the issue

Comment: @Zokulko Those `resp` and `name` fields that you don't see, what are you referring to? Is it (1) the API response from your server, or (2) the body fields of your API request, or (3) the props that `TabContent` accept?

Comment: If you can get the plain/html text like I said then the request should have no problem sending those fields. See my Codesandbox, open the console and press submit to see it correctly gets the HTML text of each editor

Comment: The thing is that I'm not even able to retrieve those 2 fields in my data i.e `resp` and `name` from the output json  from my API  (I've added it in the issue) and display them (I can display all  the other fields except those 2). I can see in my console log the content of my data but I'm enable to display the content of `resp` and `name` in the textarea box... The output that I've added in my issue is the data from my API.

Comment: @Zokulko oh wait, do you mean that you want to pass something like `<strong>Hello</strong>` into `resp` prop of `TabContent` and see the bold `Hello` text inside that resp editor?

Comment: Yeah could be this example with bold, italic or without it. But it's not working for both cases `resp` and `name`. Suppose that the user have written `<strong>Hello</strong>` in my textarea, the data in my api will have this field : `resp:Hello`, but if I want to get this info from my api: `resp` in bold (or not) nothing is printed. Same issue for `name`.

Comment: what is the difference between this `const [respState, setRespState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());` and what I've written `const [respState, setRespState] = useState(() => EditorState.createEmpty());` please ?

Comment: @Zokulko the expression you wrote means `respState` is a function and thus is not valid to pass into Editor. Removing the `() =>` makes it an EditorState, which is what it should be

Comment: @Zokulko this is confusing. Is the API you are referring to the `fetch` call inside TabContent or something else, because you’re not reading the response from that fetch call, but in Tabs you do pass in some `data` which I assume is the API response you are talking about. Please try to explain your data flow through each component clearly

Comment: Right, I've modified my issue by adding more code. I'm calling my `Tabs` in another component `MenuItemDetail`. Is it better ?

Comment: @Zokulko It is. To confirm one more time before I write you a solution, is this what you want: after getting the API response inside `MenuItemDetail`, you set it to the `responses` state, which is then passed down to Tabs, then TabContent. Here, you want to read its `resp` and `name` props then display whatever they contain in the two corresponding editors, correct?

Comment: Yeah  correct ! it's  what I want...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245817/discussion-between-son-nguyen-and-zokulko).

Comment: I've got a weird thing happening, I let you a message in the chat (don't know if we  receive the notifs in the chat?)

Comment: @Zokulko I've replied

Comment: I've send you the link for my code

Comment: @Zokulko Let's continue in the chat